# Select data frame columns when their names are contained in a vector, but keeping the same original order

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame with a column header, and a vector of string character.

So far, in the data frame I can keep the column names that match the character string in the vector. However the resulting truncated data frame displays columns by alphabetical order and not by the order in the original vector.

```
# the data frame
df <- head(t(USArrests))

# the vector of string character
v <- c("Wyoming", "Alabama", "California", "Arizona")

# subsetting the data frame by column names contained in the vector
df[,which(colnames(df) %in% v)]
         Alabama Arizona California Wyoming
Murder      13.2     8.1        9.0     6.8
Assault    236.0   294.0      276.0   161.0
UrbanPop    58.0    80.0       91.0    60.0
Rape        21.2    31.0       40.6    15.6
```

But I am trying to keep the original order in the vector, like so:

```
         Wyoming    Alabama California  Arizona
Murder       6.8       13.2        9.0      8.1
Assault    161.0      236.0      276.0    294.0
UrbanPop    60.0       58.0       91.0     80.0
Rape        15.6       21.2       40.6     31.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
df[,which(colnames(df) %in% v)]
```

Just use:

```
df[, v]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subset()` function:

```
subset(df,select=c(v))
```